# Как объединить два DBGRID?

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

[image: Эл.журнал]
Здравствуйте,нашел картинку ,каким образом можно объединить DBGRID , как на картинке.Т.е когда меняется курсор на первом DBGrid ,то второй идет за ним.

Comment: Другими словами, Вам требуется реализовать отношение "master-detail" между датасетами. Информации об этом море в интернете и в любых книгах по Delphi

Comment: Спасибо,буду искать,а вы случаем не знаете как,можно также проставить дату,т.е все дни месяца или это вручную ?

Comment: "Master-detail" - это про отношения между строками наборов данных. Соответственно, колонки здесь не участвуют. Поэтому дни месяца (как колонки грида) придётся проставлять "вручную", по событию изменения текущей вкладки (или как сочтёте нужным).

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение